# About "git merge" to merge one commit?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

In the codeaurora Kernel, I saw lots of merge commit:

```
8beeb1e Merge "qseecom: check buffer size when loading firmware images"
10f00f5 Merge "msm: mdss: Clear compat structures before copying to user"
7e9e0b6 msm: cpp: Fix for buffer overflow in cpp.
ef19b0a Merge "net: rmnet_data: Disable generic receive offload by default"
fb864c7 Merge "Input: synaptics: check input, prevent sysfs races"
9232334 Merge "msm: camera: sensor: Validate eeprom_name string length"
3c6a873 Merge "qcrypto: protect potential integer overflow."
04c3de7 Merge "msm: camera: fix bound check of offset to avoid overread overwrite"
7752a0f Merge "msm: camera: eeprom: Validate the power setting size"
682a189 net: rmnet_data: Disable generic receive offload by default
9825755 qcrypto: protect potential integer overflow.
3fc578c msm: camera: fix bound check of offset to avoid overread overwrite
e9e48ad msm: camera: sensor: Validate eeprom_name string length
789bab0 msm: camera: eeprom: Validate the power setting size
f57ac38 qseecom: check buffer size when loading firmware images
```

I don't know why there are so many merge commit in `"git log"`?
Seems that codeaurora is using `"git merge"` to `cherry-pick` one commit? What commands and parameters codeaurora is using to merge one commit to production branch?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the repository you are talking about?

Comment: Hi, link is: git://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-3.18

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, these merges you see are actual merge commits. If you cherry-pick a commit, then it will add the entire commit including its message at the current `HEAD`.

Reading this log, it seems to me that those small features/bugfixes have been created in separate branches and have then been merged/rebased onto the production branch creating the log entry.

Comment: Thanks. I want to cherry-pick some patches from master branch. But cherry-pick will change the commit ID, "git merge" doesn't change commit ID, but cannot select specific patch. I don't want to change commit ID, so that I can check which commit is not ported by "git log engineer_branch...master_branch". Can the cherry-pick patch keep commit ID not change?

Comment: @Yan No, you can't. A commit references to its parental commit, and this reference is included when creating the commit hash. If you cherry-pick a commit, the new commit has a different parent than the old commit, therefore changing the commit hash. If you *have* to use cherry-picking you should not be afraid of changing the commit hash...

Comment: @Yan Why are you afraid of changing the commit SHA?

Comment: HI, because we have the production branch and master, we will port some commits from master branches as needed. But if the commit SHA is changed, I cannot use "git log production...master" to find out which commit is ported, which is not ported yet. Is my operation error? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but `git log production...master` might even work in this case. I recommend you to change your workflow though, better have feature branches and then merge the branch to production when you need it. You will run into trouble pretty sure...

Comment: "git log production...master " only check the commit SHA. Master branch is maintailed by another team, with dozens of commits everyday. We need to cherry-pick bug fixs from master branch to production in most of time. And normally every several monthes, we need to review which commit is not ported by "git log production...master". So it it not the right workflow? Could you please tell me the normal workflow? We use SVN before...

Comment: @Yan The normal workflow would be that the other team does not commit everything to master but to separate branches which you can merge then. I don't know if that's possible for you, it seems as if you have no influence on the other teams work. Think about normal cherry-picking them and compare the logs differently...

Answer (score 1):

[Cherry-picking](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) and [merging](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) are two different Git operations that have very different purposes.

The usual workflow and a project is to create separate branches for new features and bug fixes. The developers work on these branches and when the feature is complete (on a feature branch) or the bug is fixed (on a bug-fix branch) the branch is merge into the master branch.

Cherry-picking is a technique that is used to copy a commit from a branch to another branch when a merge or a rebase is not possible. It is used, for example, when a commit on a feature branch fixes a bug or implements a functionality that is needed/useful on another feature branch.

Answer (score 0):

AOSP repositories are managed by Gerrit. Here's the basic workflow.

1. Download the repositories via `git clone` or `repo sync`.
2. Checkout a branch and work on it.
3. When commits are done, push to `refs/for/<target_branch>`.
4. A change and its first patch set is created for every new commit on Gerrit. Every patch set is a commit, pointed to by a ref in the format of `refs/changes/xx/yyyxx/1`. Imagine a new branch(ref) is created for every commit on Gerrit. `yyyxxx` is a unique id for every change. `1` is the sequence number of patch sets. It could be any number bigger than 1 if new patch sets are created.
5. Reviewers review the last patch set of a change. If it's qualified, `refs/changes/xx/yyyxx/<last>` is submitted or merged into the target branch. If it's not, the committer needs to amend the commit and push it again (or edit on Gerrit) so that a new patch set(sometimes a new change) will be created to be reviewed.

Many users may be working on the same base commit and then push their own commits. Many local branches are created in local repositories of different users. These local branches(or more specifically, new commits of these local branches) become `refs/changes/xx/yyyxx/1` after being pushed to Gerrit. These commits will be applied into the target branch when the refs `refs/changes/xx/yyyxx/1` are merged. These refs are diverged and the tip of the targt branch is constantly moving on. Therefore many merge commits are created. Gerrit supports rebase and cherry-pick, but merge is the most widely used.